# SetUserData from Box2D libary, resulting in Exception thrown at 0x010110077

Tags: c++, box2d, sfml

I am new to Box2D, and I wanted to create a body that would SetUserData of 2 different players but it results in "Exception thrown at 0x01011007 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000094."

I already tried to do player_body[0]->SetUserData("player1"); but it says cannot convert from const char to void*

```
b2Body* player_body[2]; 
player_body[0]->SetUserData((void*)"player1");
player_body[1]->SetUserData((void*)"player2");
```

Comment: The variables player_body[0] and player_body[1] contain uninitialized pointers. You need to allocate memory first.

Comment: so like this: string* player1 = new string("player1");
players[0]->SetUserData(player1);

Comment: No, the problem is not the string, it is the player_body[] pointers. You need to create the objects using `b2Body* player_body[2] = { world->CreateBody(&bodyDef) , world->CreateBody(&bodyDef)};`, where `world` is a `b2World` object, and `bodyDef` is a `b2BodyDef` object.

Comment: Is this how you would do it: `b2BodyDef bodyDef;
 b2World* world;

 b2Body* player_body[2] = {
  world->CreateBody(&bodyDef), world->CreateBody(&bodyDef)
 };
  
 player_body[0]->SetUserData((void*)"player1");`

Comment: Almost. However, you recreated the same problem you previously had: `world` is an uninitialized pointer. You need to create a world object before. But this is getting out of the scope of this question. I suggest you follow a tutorial on Box2D (see [here](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/introduction)).